# setting marker on google map is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a JSON data which has lat and long values for cities. I need to place it on Google map and put markers on it. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<div id = "map">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function init(){
      var options = {
        zoom:11,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(37.542571,-121.993037)
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),options);
    }; 
    var jsonData = {
      "locations":
        {
          "location":
            [
              {
                "id": "0001",
                "type": "RetailLocation",
                "address": "Fremont, CA 94538",
                "latitude":37.542571,
                "longitude":-121.993037,
                "$revenue": 10000000
              },
              {
                "id": "0002",
                "type": "RetailLocation",
                "address": "Newark, CA",
                "latitude": 37.525400,
                "longitude":-122.037764,
                "$revenue": 3000000
              },
              {
                "id": "0003",
                "type": "RetailLocation",
                "address": "4100-4198 Pleiades Pl,Union City, CA 94587",
                "latitude": 37.587546,
                "longitude":-122.066716,
                "$revenue": 120000000
              },
              // ...
            ]
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.each(jsonData.locations.location,function(key,json){
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(json.latitude,json.longitude);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng
        });
        marker.setMap(map); 
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

I tried to debug the problem. I am getting the lat and long values from each loop. However, when I try to put it on the map using a marker, it does not show up. Can someone help me?

Comment: here's your code working in a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/81zteyuh/1/ - notice the CSS, and the marker code placed inside init, and the callback=init added to the script src

Comment: alternatively, there's this too https://jsfiddle.net/81zteyuh/2/ - again, the CSS addition, but in this case there's no callback added, and ALL code is run in document ready - and no async/defer required for the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your callback to google script. Document. OnReady will not trigger map ready event.

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: in this case, you'd also need to move the `$.each(jsonData.locations.location` into `init` rather than jquery's "document ready" - and, the `div id="map"` needs some height! otherwise you end up with a zero height map!